# Why is LuaLaTeX not picking up small caps glyphs?

Tags: luatex, fontspec

I have a font, whose font table is as shown in the image. However, when I compile a  basic document with LuaLaTeX, the text appears as lower case, though small caps is specified.

I understand, from looking at the font table, that the small caps glyphs may be in the wrong location (in the font table) and/or have wrong labels (e.g. small caps 'a' is shown as LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A in the image below). I do not understand font tables well and any insights will be appreciated.

Please advise if I need to move the small caps gylphs to another location in the table, to allow LuaLaTeX to pick it up correctly.

If my understanding is wrong, please can you suggest any other resolution?

[image: Fonttable]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Required,Common,Contextual,TeX},Numbers=Lining, ItalicFont={Alcala-Italic},BoldFont={Alcala-Bold}]{Alcala-Regular}

\begin{document}    
\textsc{test}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: The name of the glyph looks wrong, it should be something like A.sc (but capital small caps doesn't make much sense). Beside this: moving glyphs around doesn't help, the lookup table must be correct.

Comment: For me, the name of the glyph does sound right (it is defined as variant glyph) as it is called "a.smcp" which is "a small caps", but I am unsure if fontspec supports variant glyphs as small caps shape.

Comment: This seems to be a [commercial font](http://www.editions205.fr/alcala_article_e.html), with many pirated versions circulating. Do you have the real thing? (Pirated copies will be broken in various ways.) If so, how do you invoke it?

Comment: I am playing around and I feel that the solution might have something to do with 
    SmallCapsFeatures = {  RawFeature={+smcp}}. It worked once and hasn't since.

Comment: I have a few fonts in which one or another feature works only if I specify `Script=Default`; that may be worth a try.

Comment: What happens if you define a command, say `\def\smcp#1{{\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=+smcp}#1}}` or `\def\smcp#1{{\addfontfeatures{Letters=SmallCaps}#1}}`, and use `\scmp{test}`?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the font table is mapped to replace Latin capital glyphs to small caps glyphs as shown in this image below (and not Latin small letters to small caps as is usually the case.)

[image: Caps toSC]

Now, using the \textsc command on capital letters, produces the right output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Alcala-Regular}

\begin{document}    
\textsc{\uppercase{test for small caps}}\enspace TEST FOR ALL CAPS
\end{document}
```

[image: scfine]

Comment: That’s bizarre: according to the [PDF specimen](https://www.205.tf/), the font is supposed to have both the `c2sc` and the `smcp` features, but it looks as though `smcp` was defined the way `c2sc` would be.